# Open my addon html page inside current window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, firefox-addon

When my addon is started, I want it open some predefined html page in the current window. is it possible and how do I do it?

Currently I am able to open my addon page in a new window with the following command.

```
bridge.boot = function() {
  bridge.recorderWindow = window.open("chrome://addon_name/content/html/gui.html",
    "addon_name", "width=550,height=600,toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,
    status=yes, menubar=no,  scrollbars=yes,copyhistory=no,resizable=yes");
}
```

while I call bridge.boot() from browser.xul as following.

```
    <keyset>
        <key id="selenium-builder-run-key"
            modifiers="accel alt"
            key="B"
            oncommand="bridge.boot()" />
    </keyset>
```

If I want to open gui.html in the current tab or a new tab in the current wondow and change user focus into the new tab, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [addTab](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/tabbrowser#m-addTab) function to add a new tab in the current window:

```
gBrowser.addTab("chrome://addon_name/content/html/gui.html");
```

Or you can use the [loadURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/browser#Methods) function to load a new page in the current tab:

```
gBrowser.selectedBrowser.loadURI("chrome://addon_name/content/html/gui.html");
```